# Unable to start vsftpd service on CentOS 6.6

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, init.d

I have installed `vsftpd` ftp server on CentOS 6.6 with `yum`, But I can't start vsftpd service.

When I run

`/etc/init.d/vsftpd start`,  I get

```
Starting vsftpd for vsftpd:         [FAILED]
```

with no error,

and no relevant error is listed in my `/var/log/messages` but
after installing vsftpd, I have this line in it :

```
ip-10-252-65-122 pure-ftpd[28837]: (?@2.147.232.22) [INFO] Timeout - try typing a little faster next time
```

I tried to google the error, but I found nothing.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

check to see if you have another FTP service currently running on the machine

```
netstat -anp | grep :21
```

if it is occupying the port, vsftpd can't start.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Multicraft ? if you use multicraft, the command `netstat -anp | grep :21` will return

```
tcp        0      0 YOUR_IP_ADRESS:21            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      14250/multicraft
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
service vsftpd stop
chkconfig vsftpd off
```

Then again start the service it will work